# Issues compiling GLFM with Emscripten and CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten

I am trying to compile [GLFM](https://github.com/brackeen/glfm) using emscripten and cmake. I followed the instructions on the GitHub page to do so, and the cmake command to generate all of the project files works without a hitch (other than some deprecation warnings), but when I enter the line `cmake --build .` I get errors.

Here is the entire output:

```
E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten>cmake --build .
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.85.37198 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 4/27/2018 3:21:04 PM.
Project "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ZERO_CHECK
.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Win32\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).

Project "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\glfm.vcxpr
oj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "glfm.dir\Debug\glfm.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe /c /IE
  :\emproj\glfm\include /IE:\emproj\glfm\src /nologo /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /O2 /Oy- /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\""
   /D _MBCS /Gm- /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"glfm.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"glfm.dir\Debug\glfm.
  pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue  -g -Weverything -Wwrite-strings -Wno-padded -Wno-covered-switch-defaul
  t E:\emproj\glfm\src\glfm_platform_emscripten.c
cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Weverything' [E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\glfm.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\glfm.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\glfm.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Weverything' [E:\emproj\glfm\build\emscripten\glfm.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.68
```

Its complaint is with the argument `/Weverything`. I looked in the project's CMakeLists.txt file and it looks like this command is only supposed to be used if the active compiler is clang. Could this be the issue? It is using visual studio as a host, should it be doing that?

It says that emscripten 1.35.0 is required and that's the exact version I'm using.

I also followed the instructions to get it running in Android Studio and it worked without a hitch.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is as follows:

Don't use windows.

I used Ubuntu and everything went excellently aside from installing a modern version cmake. After searching for a while the method for doing that which worked for me can be found here: https://peshmerge.io/how-to-install-cmake-3-11-0-on-ubuntu-16-04/